# VS Code or Visual Studio for ASP.NET development

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, workflow

I've always used VS Code for coding in javascript and now I'll have to learn C# for .NET and was told that I should use Visual Studio for it. Is there really anything I wouldn't be able to do in VS Code? Visual Studio seems just unnecessarily heavy besides not having a command palette.

Answer (score 1):

You can use visual studio code for asp.net development.
you need install extension c# for code intelligence.

To run dot net application you can use cmd.

```
dotnet run
```

Please refer [Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) for more command